# Weird HTTP 403 error using Java

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using a **public** (without authentication) RESTful Web Service over HTTPS: 
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time

If I make a simple GET request via Google Chrome or Advanced REST Client (Chrome Addon), everything works fine.

If I do it with Java, I get a **HTTP 403 Error**.
I have tried it with HttpsUrlConnection and Jersey - same issue.

```
String response = Client.create().resource("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time").get(String.class);
```

Any ideas? Can't figure out where the HTTP request could differ between Java/Jersey and Advanced REST Client.

Comment: Filtering by user agent, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of jersey are you using? Are you pulling the correct imports in?

The following works just fine with jersey 2.5:

```
String response = ClientBuilder.newClient()
  .target("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Time")
  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class);
```

And it gets me something like:

> {"error":[],"result":{"unixtime":1393441220,"rfc1123":"Wed, 26 Feb 14 19:00:20 +0000"}}

Comment: I was using Jersey 1.18 and switched to Jersey 2.6. Everything works now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is forbidden while you use HTTPS URL connection, then check if the SSL validation has passed. In java, you can bypass this SSL validation HttpsURLConnection with

```
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager()
    {
        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
        {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
        {
        }
    } };

    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
```